# Eclipse Luna never completely deletes my breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

I'm on Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 and everytime I start my eclipse all breakpoints I have ever made are there, no matter how many times I delete them. I always have to go to debug panel and select "remove all breakpoints", which allows me to work for the day. Then repeat the next day on startup.

The thing is, after weeks with the same projects the amount of breakpoints accumulated is astonishing and Eclipse is starting to lag badly everytime I try to go to debug panel and remove them all. Why is eclipse not deleting *forever* all my breakpoints?

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14747120/3094731) answer?

Comment: probably an eclipse bug. have you tried to delete/moving into different directory the `.metadata` folder and then rebooting eclipse?